# Image gallery loading help / How to load images on the fly, after triggered ?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load, gallery

I have a gallery similar to this one [JulienPons](http://www.julienpons.co.uk/) . Everything works fine but when I load the page, it gets massive loading times. The fullscreen images load before the thumbnails and div elements. How can I make the images and videos load only after the thumbnail is clicked?

ps. I use the href value to assign the image slider div, then use .toggle() to change the slider # for each thumbnail.

Update

```
    <div id="featured">

            <!-- PROJECT START --><div id="dubstep" class="project">
            <ul>                
<li class="img1"><img src="gallery/dubstep-1.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" width="940" height="529"/></li>
<li class="img2"><img src="gallery/dubstep-2.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" width="940" height="529"/></li>        
<li class="img3"><img src="gallery/dubstep-1.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" width="940" height="529"/></li>
<li class="iframe"><img src="gallery/dubstep-1.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" width="940" height="529"/></li>
            </ul>
           </div><!-- PROJECT END -->
    </div>
```

I want these images to load only after I click the div with the class thumb. The way they are now, they load with the document, making the loading times really big.

```
    <div id="portfolio">
    <div id="thumbnails">

        <!--THUMBNAIL START --><div class="thumb" id="dubstep-thumb"><a href="#dubstep">
        <img src="thumbs/dubstep-bwthumb.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="169"/>
        </div><!--THUMBNAIL END -->

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you can post your code and HTML, it'll be much easier to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give an id to each of your images and set their src to a small 1x1 dummy.gif:

```
<img id="image1" src="dummy.gif" alt="Css Template Preview" width="940" height="529"/>
```

add onclick attribute to your thumb div:

```
<div class="thumb" id="dubstep-thumb" onclick="loadImage( 1 )">
```

define loadImage() in your `<head>` like this:

```
function loadImage( id ) {
    var image = document.getElementById( 'image'+id );
    image.setAttribute( 'src', 'gallery/dubstep-'+id+'.jpg' );
}
```

Comment: Modified your code so it will fit my needs :) Thank you for the help!